# Initialize recursive LIST of X depth

Tags: c#

I have a hierarchy of groups and the number I have available to start with is the last/deepest child / node. I will give an example with three but it could be any positive number.

First I have this number (mock data) 88591. With that I call the hierarchy group table and get this record.

```
ID    Depth   GroupName    ParentGroup
88591   3   6240.02.10.03   88590
```

I now know that the depth is 3 so with that information I want to make this structure only I need it to be dynamic obviously.

```
dg.Children.Add(new GroupLeafNode());
dg.Children[0].Children.Add(new GroupLeafNode());
dg.Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new GroupLeafNode());
```

This of course will create 3 at the same level which is NOT what I want.

```
new List<GroupLeafNode>(3)
dg.children[3]
```

A for loop keeps giving me an index out of range error which I understand but don't know how to resolve.

```
for (int i = 0; i < group.Depth; i++)
{
  var newNode = new List<GroupLeafNode>(1);
  dg.Children[i].children.Add(newNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
var currNode = dg.Children[0];
for (int i = 0; i < group.Depth; i++)
{
    var newNode = new List<GroupLeafNode>(1);
    currNode.Children.Add(newNode);
    currNode = currNode.Children[0];
}
```

Comment: I had to make some small tweaks but that was due to my not providing you enough info to know. Thanks that got me through my road block.